# New customer registration emails sent from server not received by some customers

Tags: email

New customer registration emails that send out the link to confirm account are logged as sent from server in the linux server logs but are not received by some customers. For example: new account with caitlin.havener@gmail.com sent and I received it right away. New account with email chavener@directtoschools.com sent and I never received. I figured that this is an email filter issue on the receivers end, but obviously we want ALL of our customers to receive the email. Does the following extension help with that issue too or please advise.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aschroder-com-smtp-pro-email-free-and-easy-magento-emailing-for-smtp-gmail-or-google-apps-email.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deliverability issues can be a number of things including:

- Email/domain blacklisting
- SPF/DKIM and DomainKeys, SenderId configuration
- Firewall/port configuration
- Mail transport misconfiguration

Check `/var/maillog` on your server (for Linux, not sure for Windows-side) and ensure proper configuration of sendmail or postfix (again, Linux).

Ashley's extension isn't going to fix any of the above issues for you, but it will allow you to point to a 3rd party email delivery service which manage the above problems.

Some trustworthy SMTP relays:

http://sendgrid.com/

http://www.socketlabs.com/

https://www.mandrill.com/

---

Beyond this basic troubleshooting I'm afraid that email delivery issues are probably more fit for Serverfault.

Comment: http://mandrill.com/ is another SMTP relay option

Comment: Updated Phil's answer to include the suggested Mandrill option.

Answer (score 2):

Reality is that you will never be able to send email which is received by 100%.

In most cases using SMTP Pro will increase your chances that the email will come through for the simple reason that your email is being sent from a server which is specifically set up to send emails (return path, reverse dns lookup, reputation actively monitored).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have some deliverability issues. SMTP PRO EMAIL is a very popular extension for Magento: it allows you to use an external SMTP service. You need an SMTP service to use with it. So the steps are:

- Sign up for a SMTP relay service
- Install SMTP PRO EMAIL
- Insert the SMTP service credentials in the extension

There are several SMTP relay services that you can use. For example: MailUp, SendGrid, Mandrill, Mailgun, MailJet, and others.

We at MailUp include SMTP relay free of charge with our email marketing platform, which is integrated with Magento. For more info, see http://www.mailup.com/landing/magento/