# Transactional Emails not sending to Hotmail

Tags: email, transactional

I am testing my transactional emails currently and have noticed that none of the emails are being sent to Hotmail addresses. I have tested with other addresses with personal domains and they receive fine, so too does Gmail account. But any Hotmail emails don't seem to get received.

Is there a reason for this? Is there a setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common with webmail providers. Look into the other answers on this forum about setting up DKIM/DomainKeys/SenderId/SPF or consider moving to a hosted SMTP service.

> Deliverability issues can be a number of things including:
>
> Email/domain blacklisting SPF/DKIM and DomainKeys, SenderId
>   configuration Firewall/port configuration Mail transport
>   misconfiguration Check /var/maillog on your server (for Linux, not
>   sure for Windows-side) and ensure proper configuration of sendmail or
>   postfix (again, Linux).
>
> Some trustworthy SMTP relays:
>
> http://sendgrid.com/
>
> http://www.socketlabs.com/

---

Source: Me. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/7632/336

Comment: Thanks, I installed the extension in that question you posted and was able to use my SMTP server for relay. Hotmail is now receiving emails!